# Arithmetic sequences with linear and squared terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

For which values of x would the expression -8, $x^2$, and 17x form the first three terms of an arithmetic sequence? In the form a + (n-1)d

I think this requires a simultaneous equation but I cannot see how it is done. I am normally comfortable with linear and quadratic simultaneous equations but this escapes me.

Answer (score 1):

Differences of consecutive terms in an AP are constant so we must have

$x^2-(-8)=17x-x^2$

That is $2x^2-17x +8=0\to x_1=1/2;\;x_2=8$

Indeed, one possibility is

$$-8,\;\frac14,\;\frac{17}{2}\to -8+(n-1)\frac{33}{4}$$

and the other

$$-8,\;64,\;136 \to -8+(n-1)72$$

Comment: Thank you, and what would happen if they were not constant terms, as in a geometric sequence?

Comment: If it is a geometric progression if the ratio between a term and the consecutive is constant. In this case $$-\frac{x^2}{8}=\frac{17x}{x^2}$$ gives a third degree equation. $x\approx -5.14256$